# Select a period of time with to_date()

Tags: oracle, between, to-date

I am trying to select a specific period of time (day and hours), in order to make an average of seconds that people spend watching a specific channel.

I tried this specific function:(to_date)

```
select  cust_id, ini_datetime,end_datetime, avg(qtd_seconds) as Avg_Sec, Channel

from crm.tmp_4

where   ini_datetime between ( to_date(2019-11-30 17:50:00.0, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') and 
to_date(2019-11-30 18:00:00.0,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') ) 
    and end_datetime between ( to_date(2019-11-30 19:40:00.0,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') and to_date(2019-11-30 19:50:00.0,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') ) 

group by cust_id,ini_datetime,end_datetime, Channel
```

but it gives me this error: "ParseException line 3:50 cannot recognize input near '17' ':' '50' ". 
Does anyone have any idea about how to solve this problem?

I also tried  to_timestamp and didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Literal strings in SQL must be surrounded by single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The value must be enclosed by quotes, so your query should be like this:

```
select  cust_id, ini_datetime,end_datetime, avg(qtd_seconds) as Avg_Sec, Channel    
from crm.tmp_4    
where ini_datetime between ( to_date('2019-11-30 17:50:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
        and to_date('2019-11-30 18:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ) 
    and end_datetime between ( to_date('2019-11-30 19:40:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
        and to_date('2019-11-30 19:50:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )     
group by cust_id,ini_datetime,end_datetime, Channel
```

Data type `DATE` does not support fractional seconds. If you need them use `TO_TIMESTAMP` instead of `TO_DATE`.

Comment: ok, I changed the where clause to :



where   ini_datetime in ( to_timestamp('2019-11-30 17:50:00.0', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), to_timestamp('2019-11-30 18:00:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') ) 
 and  end_datetime in (  to_timestamp('2019-11-30 19:40:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), to_timestamp('2019-11-30 19:50:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') ) 
group by sa,ini_datetime,end_datetime;



with the timestamp because I need the fractions.But now the output is " Line 3:26 Invalid function 'to_timestamp'". Is it because my date is "2019-11-30" and not "30-Nov-19"?

Comment: A [standard literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1__GUID-D8999522-88C6-41D7-96BA-D782CA3543DD) like `timestamp '2019-11-30 17:50:00'` would be a lot less to type.

Comment: @Mary, I would assume a simple typo. Maybe a missing quote or bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You are so close. `to_date` function takes a string and returns it to date.
You are not passing a string, but some characters which make no sense to Oracle.

Also you need to remove the parenthesis at `between` and milliseconds (`.0` and `.FF`) since they are not valid in `to_date`.

```
select cust_id, ini_datetime,end_datetime, avg(qtd_seconds) as Avg_Sec, Channel
from crm.tmp_4
where ini_datetime between  to_date('2019-11-30 17:50:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and 
to_date('2019-11-30 18:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  
    and end_datetime between  to_date('2019-11-30 19:40:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('2019-11-30 19:50:00.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
group by cust_id,ini_datetime,end_datetime, channel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [timestamp literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1__GUID-D8999522-88C6-41D7-96BA-D782CA3543DD) to make this a lot simpler and easier to read:

```
select cust_id, ini_datetime, end_datetime, channel
     , avg(qtd_seconds) as avg_sec
from   crm.tmp_4
where  ini_datetime between timestamp '2019-11-30 17:50:00' and timestamp '2019-11-30 18:00:00'
and    end_datetime between timestamp '2019-11-30 19:40:00' and timestamp '2019-11-30 19:50:00'
group  by cust_id, ini_datetime, end_datetime, channel
```